# Notification for changed SQL query result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, postgresql

Given a database with multiple tables. I want to have a mechanism that notifies me, when the result of a given query changes.

For example, I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    e_id int,
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255),
    d_id int
);

CREATE TABLE department (
    d_id int,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

and the query

```
SELECT firstname
FROM employee
JOIN department
ON employee.d_id = department.d_id
WHERE department.name = "financial";
```

I want to be notified, when I execute an insert/update/delete command on either `employee` or `department`, but only if the command execution changes the result of the query. An operation that does not change the result of the query, e.g. an update of the column `lastname` should not lead to a notification.

I would like a solution that is independent of the DBMS, but if you know a solution for a specific DBMS don't hesitate to share it :-) Especially, I am interested in postgresql, mysql and sqlite.

It would be great if the solution would also work for more complex queries, e.g. a query with subqueries and/or aggregate functions.

Another great feature would be prepared statements. For example, when I alter the given query by replacing `"financial"` by `:department_name`, I would get a parameterized notification with the department name as parameter.

I know about the trigger mechanism, however it does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find a solution that is independent of the DBMS.

SQL Server has the Service Broker, which provides exactly the ability you are looking for - you can subscribe to notifications based on a specific query, and your code will receive an event when anything changes the results of the query.

You can find more details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be exactly what I want. I wonder whether there is a similar mechanism for other DBMS?

Comment: You'd be better off stating which DBMS you're interested in and tagging the question as such - that way you'll reach people who know!